# Got lateinit property has not been initialized error when using @Autowired and @Component

Tags: spring, kotlin

This AwsSqsUtil class has a Component annotation, when I want to use it in my main function, I got error "kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property awsSqsUtil has not been initialized, how to fix this issue?

"

```
@Component
class AwsSqsUtil {
   fun sendMessageToSqs() {
  }
}
```

```
@Autowired
private lateinit var awsSqsUtil: AwsSqsUtil

awsSqsUtil.sendMessageToSqs()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where exactly is your variable declaration? Is it inside a class that is a component/service/controller/etc, or just on top level?

I expect your answer to be top lever or a normal class, since that is when you'd usually encounter this.

And the solution would be to leave the main class alone in a spring boot app. If you want something to run at start-up, you can create a fun (inside a proper spring container) that you annotate with `@PostConstruct`. This way it will run after the spring app has actually started, and you'll be able to autowire at will.